# Creating a Pivot table with VBScript

Tags: vbscript, pivot, pivot-table

I am trying to create a pivot table using VBScript. I think I am close to achieving it, but I do not know how to create the report filter and set up the filter for "Internal", or how to use sum instead of count in the values.

That is what I have now:

```
xlA1 = 1
xlDatabase = 1
xlRowField = 1
xlColumnField = 2
xlFilterField = 3

Set xlBook1 = objExcel.WorkBooks.Open(ws_path &  "FINAL.xlsx")
set rngData =xlBook1.Sheets("NONPO").Usedrange
set rngReport = xlBook1.Sheets("NONPO").Range("CE1")

set pvtCache = xlBook1.pivotCaches.add(xlDatabase, rngData.address(true, true, xlA1, true))
set pvtTable = pvtCache.createPivotTable(rngReport, "Pivot1")

pvtTable.pivotFields("Date").orientation =xlRowField
pvtTable.pivotFields("Country Code").orientation = xlColumnField
pvtTable.pivotFields("Agent Type").orientation =  xlFilterField
 '*****Here I should Use filter as "Internal"*****

pvtTable.pivotFields("Hours").orientation = xlsum  *****xlsum is not working*****
```

Comment: What is `xlDatabase` used for? Why is it set to 1?

Answer (score 0):

should work like this...

```
    With pvtTable.pivotFields("Hours")
    .orientation = 4
    .Function = xlSum
    End With
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A
[proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve
its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make
it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer
to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is what you want.

```
pt.AddDataField(pt.PivotFields("Hours"), "Hours", _
    Excel.XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum)
```

So, the whole thing should look kind of like this (modify for your specific needs).

```
Private Sub CreatePivotTable(tableName As String)
    Dim targetSheet As Excel.Worksheet = ExcelApp.Sheets.Add
    Dim ptName As String = "MyPivotTable"

    'We'll assume the passed table name exists in the ActiveWorkbook
    targetSheet.PivotTableWizard(Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, _
        tableName, targetSheet.Range("A5"))
    targetSheet.Select()

    Dim pt As Excel.PivotTable = targetSheet.PivotTables(1)

    'To be professional or merely resuable, the name could be passed as parameter
    With pt.PivotFields("Order Date")
        .Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With

    pt.AddDataField(pt.PivotFields("Order Total"), "Order Count", _
        Excel.XlConsolidationFunction.xlCount)
    pt.AddDataField(pt.PivotFields("Order Total"), "Total for Date", _
        Excel.XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum)

    '--OR--
    'AddPivotFields(pt, "Order Total", "Order Count", _
    '   Excel.XlConsolidationFunction.xlCount)
    'AddPivotFields(pt, "Order Total", "Total For Date", _
    '   Excel.XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum)

    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pt)
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(targetSheet)
End Sub
```

Comment: I thought you had to define a [PivotCache](https://excelchamps.com/blog/vba-to-create-pivot-table/#4) if you were using Excel 2000 or later?